# id is undefined when removing an element from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of object

`var Country = [];`

It is something like

```
{
    "Name" : "IND"
    "Capital" : "Delhi"
    id : someID1
},
{
    "Name" : "USA"
    "Capital" : "WS"
    id : someID2
},
{
    "Name" : "UK"
    "Capital" : "London"
    id : someID3
}
```

Now I want to delete on of the element on certain condition. But it is throwing an error for more than 2 record.

My Error is : 
**Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

My code is

```
remove : function(me, record, index){
    var CountryRec = this.Country;
    var CountryLen = this.Country.length;
    for(var i=0; i<CountryLen; i++){
        if(record.data.id == this.CountryRec[i].id){
            //delete this.checkRec[i];
            checkRec.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is throwing an error for more than 2 record. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: iterate in reverse order, then use splice or decrement `i` on removal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you have unique id, then you could leave the loop after splicing with [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

```
var CountryRec = this.Country;
var CountryLen = this.Country.length;
for (var i = 0; i < CountryLen; i++) {
    if(record.data.id == CountryRec[i].id) {
        CountryRec.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even I also thought the same but was not sure. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

```
var CountryLen = this.Country.length;
```

This condition returns 3 to you. But when you delete any element from the array, you indexes are rearranged. So for the first iteration you get an array with two elements indexed `0` and `1`. And before the last iteration your get for `i` value `2`, but your array contains one element which index is `0`. So when you run `record.data.id == this.CountryRec[i].id`, it goes to the index `2` which is undefined.

If your id's are unique, use `break`.

Comment: Yes I understood. But shall I use break here

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Country = [
{
    "Name" : "IND",
    "Capital" : "Delhi",
    'id' : 'someID1'
},
{
    "Name" : "USA",
    "Capital" : "WS",
    'id' : 'someID2'
},
{
    "Name" : "UK",
    "Capital" : "London",
    'id' : 'someID3'
}];

var CountryRec = this.Country;
var CountryLen = this.Country.length;
for(var i=0; i<CountryLen; i++){
    if('someID2' == this.CountryRec[i].id){
        console.log(this.CountryRec.splice(i,1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to @SurenSrapyan's answer.

The function "splice" changes the array. So if `checkRec` is a reference to an array, and there is another reference to same array, this could cause issues. That's because how JS handles references to objects. You will need to do proper clone when creating `checkRec`. There are many different ways to do an array or object clone. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605640/134824).

So for example, if you're doing something like this:

```
var checkRec = myRec;
```

instead, do it this way:

```
var checkRec = some_clone_function(myRec);
```

Comment: This is the way which also  impressed me to do change my code. Thanks for this idea